# Magento: Layered Navigation by Price - shows results but does not filter

Tags: magento, navigation, layered-navigation, layered

In the layered navigation on category/search result pages all filterable attributes and categories show and click through fine except the pricing filter. It will show results but clicking the link will reload the page but not filter the products displayed. I can set the price increment to whatever I want and that shows fine with results, yet it will not filter the page.

```
$0.50 - $0.75 (2)
$0.75 - $1.00 (10)
$1.00 - $1.25 (12)
$1.25 - $1.50 (18)
$1.50 - $1.75 (10)
$1.75 - $2.00 (2)
```

I'm not sure if it's a problem of what it passes through to the url "?price=3%2C.25" it's a bit frustrating. I'm not even sure where to start. I unfortunately have not found a similar situation.

Comment: set on "Flat Catalog Category" and "Flat Catalog Category" then refresh index and cache.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I tried your suggestion but still no filtering happening.